# how to trigger dvd's autoplay programmatically

Tags: dvd, autoplay

I want to enable auto-playing on DVD drive (specifically, virtual one created using UltraISO - they don't support the auto-play yet) so that when I click on some shortcut, the auto play of drive E: will execute.

I wouldn't mind using vbs, cmd, ahk or whatever :)

Comment: What operating system are you dealing with?

Comment: How does this make it easier than clicking the shortcut?

Comment: windows 7, please note the context menu command of auto-play is under ultraiso sub menu.

Comment: Can't you just make a shortcut to your media player, and pass it `E:\ ` as the argument (i.e. so it loads the DVD)?  AFAIK, this works with VLC, and should work with all media players that support dragging-and-dropping media files onto the program/shortcut itself.

Answer (score -1):

By default, you should **disable** all autoplay features on your computer.   Autoplay is a huge security risk when enabled, since programs are launched without your explicit action/permission.

Assuming you simply want a shortcut that plays the DVD video of whatever is in drive `E:`, you should be able to create a shortcut on your desktop to the media player, and pass it the path to the DVD drive as the only argument.  For example, using VLC, create a shortcut with the following as the *target*:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "E:\"
```

Clicking the shortcut should start playing whatever DVD is in drive `E`.  Depending on your media player, you may have to modify the shortcut arguments, but the above should work for all media players which support drag-and-drop onto the executable.

Comment: I don't want to "play" the content, rather "auto-play". yes, despite the security risk - I wouldn't mind getting the window's dialog box "what do you want to do (open/view files)"